# How do I enable code-completion in Netbeans 6.8 for facelets in JSF 1.2?

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, jboss, facelets

I'd like to enable code completion for facelets + JSF 1.2 in NetBeans 6.8.  I'd prefer to enable it for a free-form project that I build using my own Ant build.xml, but I see no options to enable that, so I'm willing to go with a "Web Application with Existing Sources".

*Sorry for all of the screen-shots.* I just want to show what I did.

**Project Setup**

[image: Choose a Project dialog]

[image: Name & Location dialog]

[image: Server & Settings dialog]

[image: Existing Sources & Libraries dialog]

**Project Configuration**
[image: Frameworks dialog with Libraries tab selected]

[image: Frameworks dialog with Configuration tab selected]

After setup and configuration, code-completion within facelets still doesn't work.
[image: Showing editor with failed code-completion]

Am I missing something?  Am I going about this in the wrong way?

## Solution

Here's what I ended up doing:

1. I switched from a Standard Java project to a Web project (duh!)
2. I took [Awano's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254719/awano) and switched the MIME type for xhtml files back to text/xhtml.
3. I added the [tld file](https://facelets.dev.java.net/files/documents/3448/21641/jsf-ui.tld) from the [facelets site](https://facelets.dev.java.net/) to the meta-inf directory in the jsf-facelets.jar and included it in my project.
4. I added the *rendered* attribute to the fragment tag in the jsf-ui.tld file.  It was missing for some reason:

   ```
   <attribute>
       <name>rendered</name>
       <required>false</required>
       <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
       <description>Renders the contents of this tag if the attribute resolves to true.</description>
   </attribute>
   ```

Comment: I don't do Netbeans, so I have really no idea. But similar problem exist in Eclipse. All you need to do in Eclipse is to associate `*.xhtml` files with the JSP editor (which by default only runs on `*.jsp`, `*.jspx` and so on). See if similar setting exist in Netbeans. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I fiddled with changing the associated mime type, but that had no affect on code completion.  (It did affect tag matching and code formatting, though.)

Comment: if BalusC's solution doesn't work, you might take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136218/eclipse-autocomplete-content-assist-with-facelets-jsf-and-xhtml/2136362#2136362 - it is about eclipse, but the linked articles/tld are probably applicable to netbeans as well.

Comment: Bozho, I took a look at the question you linked to.  I tried manually referencing the TLD files, but it had no affect.  I'll keep poking around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the facelet libs in the libraries of your project properties? 
Otherwise check that in Tools / Options / Miscellaneous / Files that xhtml is associated with MIME XHTML (text/xhtml).

Comment: I added the "JSF 1.2 + Facelets 1.1.14 library" and it had no affect.  I also tried switching to the text/xhtml MIME type.  It also had no affect.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you use the official Netbeans 6.8? It seems they were some bugs on xhtml autocompletion in intermediary builds.

Comment: As far as I know.  I'm running NetBeans IDE 6.8 (Build 200912041610)

Comment: THANK YOU! Our team has named our Facelets files with the .JSF extension and I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why I didn't get any code completion.