# Ecplise autocomplete primefaces tags

Tags: eclipse, jsf, facelets, primefaces

I am using Eclipse to work with PrimeFaces like this:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui" 
 template="/template/ui.xhtml">
```

I saw [Bozho question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136218/eclipse-autocomplete-content-assist-with-facelets-jsf-and-xhtml).

So it works for me only for h and f tags and not for p (primefaces) tag! How can it autocomplete primefaces tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've blogged about Helios support, that might help;

http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/primefaces-support-in-eclipse-helios/

Comment: I was using the demo war - primefaces-rc1. so please add it to it as well.

Comment: In Indigo SR1 tag autocompletion works fine for PrimeFaces 3.0M3, but not for latest (m4) release. A bug?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and none of the solutions posted solved (i already had primefaces jar in my classpath).

I use a eclipse project format, and in the .settings folder, the file "org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml" had this properties:

```
<installed facet="jst.jsf" version="1.2"/>
<installed facet="jst.web" version="2.5"/>
```

I changed to:

```
<installed facet="jst.jsf" version="2.0"/>
<installed facet="jst.web" version="3.0"/>
```

And it worked. Sure it was a wrong configuration, but can be useful to someone.
Ps: these properties can be changed in project facets on eclipse project properties, but in some cases it´s better change directly in the file.

Answer (score 0):

By default we don't get automcomplete for PrimeFaces tag in Eclipse. To enable AutoComplete,
Go to Window-->Preferences-->General-->ContentTypes
Select JSP and add .xhtml as file association.