# How to make eclipse to support PrimeFaces EL auto complete

Tags: eclipse, jsf, primefaces, el, content-assist

I'm using PrimeFaces with Eclipse. but I don't know how to configure eclipse to support
EL auto complete in to primeface component
i have install the plugin according to the below post

[How do I Install JBoss AS / WildFly Server in Eclipse for Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057328/how-do-i-install-jboss-6-in-eclipse-helios-java-ee/4057346#4057346)

but the case is, it only supports for JSF component

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060600/ecplise-autocomplete-primefaces-tags

Comment: auto complete works fine but i have the issue with el expresion auto complete as eg: when i type #{bean.} after i press ctrl+space it dosen't shows the method in backing bean