# JBoss Tools JSF code completion does not work on Facelets tags

Tags: eclipse, jsf, facelets, jboss-tools

I am using Eclipse Indigo and JBoss Tools 3.3.0. In a XHTML file the code completion works fine for JSF tag like `<h:...>` or `<f:...>`, but not for Facelets tags, like `<ui:...>`.

Does anything specific have to be configured for this to work?

Comment: Nothing else should be configured. I have also not seen this problem before. Is there any chance that you're having old Facelets 1.x libraries in the classpath?

Comment: I generated a project with jboss forge and imported in eclipse. The pom contains this dependencies: <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>

Comment: <dependencies><dependency><groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId><scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency><groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency><dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
<artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: <dependency><groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope></dependency><dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>

Comment: <dependency><groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
<artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
<version>3.0</version></dependency><dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
<version>2.1.6</version></dependency></dependencies>

Comment: may be you want to go through this link


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136218/eclipse-autocomplete-content-assist-with-facelets-jsf-and-xhtml

Comment: I reinstall eclipse with only jboss tools plugin and it worked. So it maybe a conflict with something else

Answer (score 0):

Should just work. Does your XHTML have the ui namespace defined ?

If not open bug at Jira.jboss.org/browse/jbide

Thanks