# eclipse jsf as you type validation doesnt work

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I have xhtml files for jsf in eclipse java EE indigo,
but the as i type (autocomplete) is not working.

I have tried turning on as you type jsf validation, but no change, 
am i missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse autocomplete (content assist) with facelets (jsf) and xhtml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136218/eclipse-autocomplete-content-assist-with-facelets-jsf-and-xhtml)

Comment: yes this does seems a duplicate, but that questions answer does NOT work for me, so maybe a new answer is worth adding?