# IceFaces 1.8 tags doesn't autocomplete in XHTML, only in JSP

Tags: eclipse, jsf, icefaces, jboss-tools

I'm using facing with strange behaviour which I do not understand.

- Eclipse  : 4.4 Luna
- JSF      : 1.2
- IceFaces : 1.8
- Eclipse plugin : JBoss Tools

When I'm editing (JSP Editor) *.xhtml file there is code complete for h:, f: and ui: but not for ice: (IceFaces) available,
but when I renamed file to *.jsp (without any change in its content) code complete is available for all tags.

I was trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136218/eclipse-autocomplete-content-assist-with-facelets-jsf-and-xhtml) but it wont help. Same thing when using 'JBoss Tools JSP Editor'.

My file content:

```
<ice:panelGroup xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">

    <h:inputText value="example" />

</ice:panelGroup>
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I am not familiar with Eclipse but the reason might be that you are using the legacy JSF 1.2 (with JSP files). Recent IDEs may not adequately incorporate the functionality. Does this happen while using Facelets (hereby not JSPs)?

Comment: I don't know IceFaces, but this can happen if it doesn't have a Facelets taglib at all, but only a JSP taglib. You may want to try JSPX instead.

Comment: Guys, thanks for answers.
@Tiny I'm using Facelets

Comment: @BalusC For *.JSPX all tags works well (even IceFaces one), but as far as I know this is variation of JSP file. Moreover I don't know is it possible to use *.jspx files in my case (I'm using IceFaces with portlets) - I have to check this out.

Comment: OK, check Eclipse preferences in *General > Editors > File Associations* and compare JSPX with XHTML. Check if JSPX has a different associated editor and then reconfigure XHTML to use the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

1. You are using JBoss Tools HTML Editor
2. You have icefaces-comps.jar in your Eclipse project's class path
3. Project properties -> JBoss Tools Knowledge Base -> Support is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Add icefaces plugin to eclipse.
2. Right click on the project and go to properties
3. Go to project facelets
4. Add icefaces facelet to project.

That's it. Now you should be getting the autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Icefaces plugin interfers with JBoss Tool Editor.

I get the autocomplete to work when i drop the IceFaces plugin.

xhtml extension must be declared in JSP with other JSP extensions.

```
Window > Preferences > General > Content Types > Text > JSP > Add (xhtml)
```

Hope this will save time.