# JSF 2.0 Faces Flow support in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, jsf-2, faces-flow

Does anyone know if the Faces Flow feature of JSF 2.0 is supported in Eclipse or in IntelliJ?

I'm searching for some plugin to get autocompletion for EL-expressions (i.e. Beans, sessionScope-, flowScope-variables) and Tags in faces-config xml-files and xhtml-files.

I tried it with JBoss Tools which doesn't really support Faces Flow but has a nice autocompletion for xhtml-files (not for faces-config files).

Does anyone know a better plugin for Faces Flow or does anyone know how to configure the xml-editor of JBoss Tools to get autocompletion for EL-elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a note, the Faces Flows feature is new to JSF 2.2 (JSR 344).

[Eclipse WTP](https://eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.5.0/NewAndNoteworthy/jsf.php) (Web Tools Platform) does have explicit JSF 2.2 support, so it should provide at least some subset of the features you want.

IT's also possible that you may need to do some additional configuration in Eclipse, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7242705/1713801).