# Eclipse Oxygen 3A Web Page Editor Palette Content for xhtml-Files

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I have a new Dynamic Web Project with an index.xhtml in it.

When I open this index.xhtml in the Web Page Editor there are no jsf-tags in the Palette:
[image]

But when I rename the file to index.jsf the Palette looks like this:
[image]

Is there somewhere an option in Eclipse that I can set to make the Palette work for .xhtml-Files like it does for .jsf-Files?

Comment: Does the file have the expected doc type and root element attributes for it to be a JSF file with the .xhtml filename extension?

Comment: Is this important? I'm just doing a rename, the file content doesn't change between .jsf and .xhtml.

Comment: Took a while but today I stumbled upon this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136218/eclipse-autocomplete-content-assist-with-facelets-jsf-and-xhtml