# I have an Eclipse IDE for java development. How can i use the same IDE for JSP?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, web

I have installed Eclipse photon for pure java. Now I want to use JSP. How can I develop a website using JSP in the same IDE

Comment: Install _Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools_: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53943858/6505250

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF editor autocomplete (xhtml) for STS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942884/jsf-editor-autocomplete-xhtml-for-sts-4)

Comment: @howlger JSP and JSF are entirely different things.

Comment: @nitind Sure, but both are supported by WTP, aren't they?

Comment: @howlger That is true.

Answer (score 1):

Install the Web Tools Platform and you can use its support for JSPs. The most critical part for that is the **Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools** feature, but you'll need the **Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools** feature if you want to use Eclipse to run and debug your web app on a server.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F